# Spring boot war with embedded tomcat causing performance issues for jsps

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp, embedded-tomcat-8

We've lots of `jsps` in our application when we migrated to `spring-boot 1.5` we had to retain those. but after building a war and from there if we are running it's taking lots of time to load the page. samething from the `eclipse` or command line `gradle bootRun` it's super fast. I tried https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2825 this but there is no change. But if i use standalone tomcat it wrks fine. Is there any hack we can do for solving the problem with embedded tomcat?

Comment: did you tried setting server.jsp-servlet.init-parameters.development=false in bootstrap.yml or any other application config file your using.

Comment: yes i've tried bt  it's nt working.

Comment: Did you ever figure out your issue?  I updated a model on my own project and the startup went from 8 seconds to 80+ seconds... Would like to know if anything helped your situation.

Comment: This post helped me with this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62759292/12284870